# Azure - Network Path Not Found

Tags: sql-server, azure, networking

I have 4 Azure VMs which are part of the same resource group and virtual network. 3 of them are running SQL Sever and 1 of them is configured as a domain controller. The 3 SQL VMs are getting there DNS from the DC.

The VMs can log into the domain and see each other on the network. When I try to use connect to SQL instances across the virtual network, however, I receive a network path not found error.

I have renamed the instances and even tried removing and re-installing them. So I am sure it is a network issue, and not a SQL Server problem. I also can't connect via IP address, so it doesn't seem to be DNS.

The instances are all default instances and are connected on 1433, the VMs all have TCP 1433 endpoints and Windows Firewall is turned off.

Comment: Wich method are you using to connect to sql instances? what is the connection string? Have you tried connecting thru SQL console client?

Comment: I have tried connecting through SSMS, SQLCMD and can't telnet to the port

Comment: DC not On Premise

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Enable the Port from Azure Services As well

Comment: I have created the endpoints, as I mentioned in my question. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Try to telnet the iPhone and the port number

Comment: **Could not open connection to host on Port 1433: Connect Failed.** I should say that these server/instances could communicate perfectly, before they joined the domain

Answer (score 0):

> The instances are all default instances and are connected on **1434**, the
>   **VMs all have TCP 1433** endpoints, and Windows Firewall is turned off.

Ensure you have both ports open in all machines. **1433**, **1434**

Also remember that disable windows firewall is just a temporary thing, you should re-enable it once the connection test pass.

**Note** that depending of your kind of connection/services you also should open:

- 1433:  / TCP / UDP
- 80: For sync over HTTP / TCP
- 443: SQL Server default instance running over an HTTPS endpoint / TCP
- 4022: Service Broker / TCP
- 135: Transact-SQL debugger  / TCP
- 7022: Defacto database mirroring / TCP
- 2383: SQL Server Analysis Services
- 2382: connection requests to a named instance of Analysis Services

Comment: Hi, sorry, 1434 was a typo. Default instances connected on 1433. 1434 UDP not required. Yes, Win F/W is temporary. I know what ports I require, thanks. I just need some assistance from the networking angle, as to why I can't connect to the ports, across the virtual network, after configuring a domain

Comment: did you add the Domain DNS to the Azure VNET DNS?